# VBA Range.Find method returns error when text exists

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to program a UDF for a Case-sensitive `VLOOKUP`. The goal is to mimic the `VLOOKUP` arguments, but to return only if a case-sensitive match is found. This is what I have so far

```
Function CaseVLOOKUP(lookup_value As Variant, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Integer, range_lookup As Boolean)

Dim search_col As Range
Dim return_col As Range
Dim result As Variant
Dim row_index As Double

Set return_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table_array, 0, col_index_num)
Set search_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table_array, 0, 1)

row_index = search_col.Find(lookup_value, MatchCase:=True, LookIn:=xlValue).Row
result = return_col(row_index)


'Debug.Print result
CaseVLOOKUP = result

End Function
```

However, I get the `#VALUE` error, even if I see the text exists. The error is in the `row_index` setting line;

I know the text should exist in `return_col`, item 23. In the immediate window, I tried

```
?lookup_value=search_col(23)
```

and this returns `True`. As far as I understand `Range.Find`, this should work...
What am I missing ?

Comment: `LookIn` should be `xlValues` not `xlValue`

Comment: #facepalm indeed...